# Finding Projective Transformation of Crossing Lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

I am having difficulties with a calculation (and its given solution according to the textbook authors).  The problem is from "Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach" by Garrity et al.  In the published edition, Exercise 1.9.6, it says the following:

Consider the crossing lines

$$(a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 z)(a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2 z) = 0,$$

with

$$\text{det} \pmatrix{a_1 \ b_1 \\ a_2 \ b_2} \neq 0.$$

Find a projective change of coordinates from $xyz$-space to $uvw$-space so that the crossing lines become

$$uv = 0$$

**My calculation attempts**

We want to find a matrix $M$ such that:

$$M \pmatrix{u \\ v\\w} = \pmatrix{x \\ y \\z}.$$

Writing the first row's multiplication out with $u = a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 z$ and $v = a_2 x + b_2 y + c_3 z$ gives, and choosing $w = z$ (this choice is where I am the least confident... I am just trying to simplify things to see if I can get a transformation that works) to see if I can simplify gives:

$$m_{11}u + m_{12}v + m_{13}w = x$$
$$\rightarrow m_{11}(a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 z) + m_{12}(a_2 x + b_2 y + c_3 z) + m_{13}z = x$$
$$\rightarrow (m_{11}a_1 + m_{12}a_2)x + (m_{11}b_1 + m_{12}b_2)y + (m_{11}c_1 + m_{12}c_2 + m_{13})z = x$$
Equating each coefficient:
$$m_{11}a_1 + m_{12}a_2 = 1$$
$$m_{11}b_1 + m_{12}b_2 = 0$$
$$m_{11}c_1 + m_{12}c_2 + m_{13} = 0$$

Solving the second equation for $m_{11}$:
$$m_{11} = \frac{-b_2}{b_1}m_{12}$$

Plugging this into the first equation gives a solution for $m_{12}$:
$$\left(\frac{-b_2}{b_1}m_{12}\right)a_1 + m_{12}a_2 = 1$$
$$\rightarrow m_{12}\left(\frac{-b_2}{b_1}a_1 + a_2\right) = 1$$
$$\rightarrow m_{12} = \frac{1}{\frac{-b_2}{b_1}a_1 + a_2}$$
$$\rightarrow m_{12} = \frac{b_1}{{-b_2}a_1 + a_2 b_1}$$
$$\rightarrow m_{12} = \frac{-b_1}{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}$$
$$\rightarrow m_{12} = \frac{-b_1}{d}$$

Where $d =\text{det} \pmatrix{a_1 \ b_1 \\ a_2 \ b_2} \neq 0.$  Continuing, solving for $m_{11}$ gives:

$$m_{11} = \frac{-b_2}{b_1}m_{12} = \frac{-b_2}{b_1}\frac{-b_1}{d} = \frac{b_2}{d}$$

Plugging these into the third equation to solve for $m_{13}$:

$$m_{13} = -m_{12}c_2 - m_{11}c_1 = \frac{b_1 c_2}{d} - \frac{b_2 c_1}{d} = \frac{1}{d}(b_1 c_2 - b_2 c_1)$$

The case is symmetrical for the second row, and the third row yields $m_{33} = 1$, the rest of the entires zero, for a matrix of:

$$ M =\frac{1}{d}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}
b_2     & -b_1     & b_1 c_2 - b_2 c_1  \\ 
-a_2    & a_1      & a_2 c_1 - a_1 c_2   \\ 
0   & 0   & d    
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Authors' Solution**
However, the authors give a different solution, which goes:

> We want to find a matrix $M$ such that

> $$M \pmatrix{u \\ v \\ w} = \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ w}$$

> gives $a_1x + b_1 y + c_1z = u$ and $a_2 x  + b_2 y + c_2 z = v$ with this change of variables.  if you write this out you'll see this amounts to solving 3 systems of 2 equations each.  If $d = \text{det} \pmatrix{a_1 \ b_1 \\ a_2 \ b_2}$ we find

> $$ M =\frac{1}{d}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \begin{array}{rrr}
> b_2 - c_1 b_2 + b_1 c_2    & -b_1 - c_1 b_2 + b_1 c_2 & b_1 c_2 - b_2 c_1  \\ 
> -a_2 - c_2 a_1 + a_2 c_1    & a_1 - c_2 a_1 + a_2 c_1 & a_2 c_1 - a_1 c_2   \\ 
> d   & d   & d    
> \end{array}
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

They don't elaborate any further on how they got this solution.  Their bottom row seems to imply a choice of $z = u + v + w$.  I am confused as to how they got their solution, even though their solution has features that are similar to the end result of my calculation.  I would like to know

1. **Is my solution a valid solution to the problem?**
2. **How did the authors obtain their solution, in detail?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your solution**

Putting your solution for M through Pari/GP gives: $x=\frac{b_2u-b_1v+(b_1c_2-b_2c_1)w}{d}$, $y=\frac{-a_2u+a_1v+(a_2c_1-a_1c_2)w}{d}$, $z=w$ and confirms that $L_1=a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=u$ and $L_2=a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=v$ as expected, so your solution certainly seems correct.

We can also reach your solution using the language of matrices. Write the required constraints $a_1x + b_1 y + c_1z = u$ and $a_2 x  + b_2 y + c_2 z = v$, plus your choice that $w=z$, in matrix form:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
u\\v\\w\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}
a_1    & b_1 & c_1  \\ 
a_2    & b_2 & c_2  \\
0&0&1
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}x\\y\\z
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{Or, writing $A=\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}
a_1    & b_1 & c_1  \\ 
a_2    & b_2 & c_2  \\
0&0&1
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}~$,}\quad\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
u\\v\\w\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}x\\y\\z
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We see $\det A =\det\pmatrix{a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2}$, and we are given that  $\det\pmatrix{a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2}\ne 0$, so $A$ is a projective change of coordinates.

Then multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$ gives $\quad A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
u\\v\\w\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}x\\y\\z
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}\quad$ so we see immediately that the matrix $M$ we're seeking in your solution is $M=A^{-1}$, which works out exactly as you calculated.

**The Authors' solution**

I do not understand the authors' solution. Their equation $M\pmatrix{u\\v\\w}=\pmatrix{x\\y\\{\color{red}w}}$ doesn't make sense to me as a change of coordinates. Assuming it was a typo and they meant $M\pmatrix{u\\v\\w}=\pmatrix{x\\y\\{\color{red}z}}$, we can
invert their solution (using Pari/GP so avoid the tedious algebra) and write their starting assumptions as:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
u\\v\\w\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}
a_1    & b_1 & c_1  \\ 
a_2    & b_2 & c_2  \\
-a_1-a_2&-b_1-b_2&1-c_1-c_2
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}x\\y\\z
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}$$

So they've made the choice, that $w=z-(a_1x+b_1y+c_1z)-(a_2x+b_2y+c_2z)=z-u-v$, or $z=u+v+w$ as you correctly observe.  Why?  I have no idea.  But once that choice is made, getting to the matrix $M$ is just a matter of solving the equations or (equivalently) inverting the matrix.

What's less obvious is how they've used the given property that $\det\pmatrix{a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2}\ne 0$. See the notes in the general solution below.

**General solution**

Elementary row operations (EROs) do not change the determinant of a matrix. We can take your assumption matrix $A$, which clearly has the property $\det A\ne0$ given $\det\pmatrix{a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2}\ne 0$, and apply the row operation $\text{row}3\leftarrow\text{row}3+k_1\text{row}1+k_2\text{row2}$ to get a general assumption matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
u\\v\\w\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}
a_1    & b_1 & c_1  \\ 
a_2    & b_2 & c_2  \\
k_1a_1+k_2a_2&k_1b_1+k_2b_2&1+k_1c_1+k_2c_2
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}x\\y\\z
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}$$

with $w=z+k_1u+k_2v$. This gives the general solution
$$ M =\frac{1}{d}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr}
b_2 - k_1(b_1 c_2 - b_2 c_1)    & -b_1 -k_2(b_1 c_2 - b_2 c_1) & b_1 c_2 - b_2 c_1  \\ 
-a_2 - k_1(a_2 c_1 - a_1 c_2)  & a_1 -k_2 (a_2 c_1 - a_1 c_2) & a_2 c_1 - a_1 c_2   \\ 
-k_1d   & -k_2d   & d    
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So there are an infinite number of solutions.
The authors' assumption matrix corresponds to choosing $k_1=k_2=-1$. Yours corresponds to $k_1=k_2=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! This is a lesson in not letting alternative "official" solutions slow down my own intuitions and calculations.